# Geoplugin string result to German word/language

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this plugin([enter link description here](http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/javascript)) to get the **Country Name** of the site visitor using jQuery. But I want the string result to be converted into German language. So for instance the string result is Philippines, then the converted string should "Philippinen".

```
// Get Country Name(http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/javascript)
var country = geoplugin_countryName();
$('.countryName').html(country);
```

Is there any plugin or services that could get this kind of result?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Bing Translate API which has a free tier which allows up to 2,000,000 characters per month.
As far as I know that's the only free Translate API.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/getstarted.aspx